# Using Entrypoint in SuiteCRM to update a field through a E-mail link to client?

Tags: php, sugarcrm, entry-point, suitecrm

Wondering how I'd go about doing this process:

1. When Date of Deadline is LessThan OR EqualTo 7 days THEN Create a
   Task on Account **(know how to do)**
2. THEN send Email from template
   **(know how to do)**
3. In the e-mail have some way for the client to respond that updates a *[emailtickfield]* Boolean (or
   *Yes/No/NotApplicable dropdown*, not sure which we'd prefer yet) field
   in the data **(not sure how to do)**
4. *If email reminder sent
   GreaterThan 7 days and [emailtickfield] = 0* then send a email
   reminder to assigned user to contact account directly. **(know how
   to do)**

I've been informed that Entry-Points is the way to go about this, which there's a nice tutorial on how to create, but I'm still not actually sure about the workings of this process.

How would one get the entrypoint to update this field?

Comment: Have you tried anything as yet? If so, can you post your code?

Comment: I've not tried as of yet, just some of the docs are a little dated so wanted to be sure I'm doing the right method for it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The URL in the email (or maybe multiple links for each choice) would pass back the account uuid and response value to a custom entry point. Something like this:

`www.your-url?index.php?entryPoint=myCustomEntrypoint&id=d1384226-b5fb-43b9-01a7-4f54989ce3ff&response=NotApplicable`

Your entrypoint would then retrieve these values from the `$_REQUEST['id']` and `$_REQUEST['response']`, from these you can load the bean object and update the value accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest looking into logic hooks. An on-save hook for emails would run code when an email object is saved. If the from email isn't one of yours, it's incoming and you can do whatever you want with it.

Comment: Well the from e-mail would be one of ours in this instance though.